# Generate JAXBContext : newInstance(contextPath) : using jaxb.index

Tags: jaxb, jdeveloper

I found lots of answered questions and best practices related to JAXBContext generation using contextpath (package names with (:) separated). I have achieved JAXBContext using contextpath and jaxb.index(each package contains index file with list of classes contains). But still I have a question, Is it will be achieved without jaxb.index and ObjectFactory class? Is it possible? If its YES,kindly guide me and give some Links to follow.

I gone through this JAXBContext menthod summary. ( http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html ). I found this line **failure to locate either ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index in the packages**.

Please direct me if this question was answered already.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `JAXBContext` on a context path, your JAXB impl will first look for a `jaxb.index` file at that location,  if that file is not present it will automatically look for a class called `ObjectFactory` that is annotated with `@XmlRegistry`.

Comment: Thanks Blaise. I have a one more doubt,@XmlType annotation can be used in XmlRootElement class only?

Comment: @MohanrajNataraj - `@XmlType` can be used on any class.